# OnClick и OnDragDrop события срабатывают друг после друга

Tags: delphi

После события OnDragDrop в VirtualStringTree срабатывает событие OnClick, а по OnClick не срабатывает OnDragDrop. Не удобно. По клику должна редактироваться ячейка. Как можно обойти вызов события OnClick после OnDragDrop?

Comment: Обнулять в нужный момент OnClick := nil и восстанавливать после OnDragDrop

Answer (score 1):

Реализовал с помощью флага. По окончанию обработки OnDragDrop он выставляется в true, в OnClick всегда включается режим редактирования, и если флаг выставлен в true, то происходит выход из режима редактирования.